# Insert values into a temporary table under conditions and change values on insert (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two temp tables

#shovel

```
Equipment    Code     Start_Time
EX7016       1000     0
EX7016       4030     1200
EX7016       1000     1400
```

#truck

```
Equipment Shovel  Code    Start_Time
DT5188    EX7016  1002    0
DT5188    EX7016  1003    1000
DT5188    EX7016  1004    1500
DT5188    EX7016  1005    2000
```

The logic I need is if the #shovel table has code > 2000, and the time starts when the truck is in a 1003 code, then insert that time into the #truck table as a 1002 code. And once the Shovel goes back into a 1000 code, insert that time as a 1003 code, so it looks like:

```
Equipment  Shovel  Code    Start_Time
DT5188     Ex7016  1002    0
DT5188     Ex7016  1003    1000
DT5188     Ex7016  1002    1200
DT5188     Ex7016  1003    1400
DT5188     Ex7016  1004    1500
DT5188     Ex7016  1005    2000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick try at this, and here's a solution that works in multiple steps.  It's probably not fit for purpose, but at least it's a start.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#shovel') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #shovel;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#truck') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #truck;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#matches1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #matches1;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#matches2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #matches2;

SELECT 'EX7016' AS Equipment, '1000' AS Code, '0' AS Start_Time
INTO #shovel
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EX7016' AS Equipment, '4030' AS Code, '1200' AS Start_Time
UNION ALL
SELECT 'EX7016' AS Equipment, '1000' AS Code, '1400' AS Start_Time

SELECT 'DT5188' AS Equipment, 'EX7016' AS Shovel, '1002' AS Code, '0' AS Start_Time
INTO #truck
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DT5188' AS Equipment, 'EX7016' AS Shovel, '1003' AS Code, '1000' AS Start_Time
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DT5188' AS Equipment, 'EX7016' AS Shovel, '1004' AS Code, '1500' AS Start_Time
UNION ALL
SELECT 'DT5188' AS Equipment, 'EX7016' AS Shovel, '1005' AS Code, '2000' AS Start_Time;

--Make a list of cases where the #shovel table has code > 2000, and the time starts when the truck is in a 1003 code
SELECT 
    s.Equipment, 
    s.Start_Time, 
    t.Shovel
INTO 
    #matches1
FROM 
    #shovel s 
    INNER JOIN #truck t ON t.Shovel = s.Equipment
WHERE 
    s.Code > '2000' 
    AND t.Code = '1003';

--Find cases where the shovel goes back to a 1000 code
SELECT
    m.Equipment,
    s.Start_Time,
    m.Shovel
INTO
    #matches2
FROM
    #matches1 m
    INNER JOIN #shovel s ON s.Equipment = m.Equipment AND s.Start_Time > m.Start_Time AND s.Code = '1000';

--Finally, insert matching rows back into the #truck table (do we only do this if there is a match in both tables?)
INSERT INTO #truck SELECT Equipment, Shovel, '1002' AS Code, Start_Time FROM #matches1;
INSERT INTO #truck SELECT Equipment, Shovel, '1003' AS Code, Start_Time FROM #matches2;

SELECT * FROM #truck ORDER BY Start_Time;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, turns out the source data timestamps are actually incorrect so I need to parse log files to build a new table. Thanks very much for having a go though appreciate it.